# `:verbose map` doesn't list origin of some mappings

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm trying to debug a mapping of the key `Y`.

`:verbose map` gives the following snippet:

```
...
noxW           * repmo#SelfKey('W', 'B')
    Last set from ~/.dotfiles/vim/.config/vim/vimrc line 446
n  Y           * y$
o  [%            <Plug>(MatchitOperationMultiBackward)
    Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim line 75
...
```

All the other lines seem to include `Last set from`.  Why doesn't `Y`?

How do I find out the source of `Y` mapping to `y$`?

Also, what's the `*` about? Searching `:help map` for `\*` didn't turn up anything.

I'm using neovim 0.6.0.

Comment: The answer to the meaning of `*` is found under `:h map-listing` ("indicates that it is not remappable"). Add this to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `:help Y` we read:

```
Mapped to "y$" by default. |default-mappings|
```

Reading there, we find:

```
Nvim creates the following default mappings at |startup|. You can disable any
of these in your config by simply removing the mapping, e.g. ":unmap Y".

    nnoremap Y y$
    nnoremap <C-L> <Cmd>nohlsearch<Bar>diffupdate<CR><C-L>
    inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>
    inoremap <C-W> <C-G>u<C-W>
```